# create a django serializer to create three model instance at once

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```js
{
 
        "product_name": "CRVRVgfhghg",
        "product_price": "0.01",
        "product_location": "KIKUYU,KENYA",
        "product_description": "VFVFVFVFVFVF",
        "product_category_name": "livestock",
        "product_farmer_name": "james",
        "product_category_data": {
            "product_category_name": "livestock",
            "product_category_description": "livestock one"
        },
        "product_product_file_data": {
            "product_file_name": "ok"
        }
 }
```

i have three tables: `product_category,product and product_product_files`...what i want is to populate all the three tables at once using one view and url pattern... is there a way i can do this using serializers??

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the following documentation [DRF writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Looking at this you'll see that they state the following:

'*By default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create create() and/or update() methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved:*'

This is the example they use:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']


class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

The data they put in then should look like this:

```
data = {
'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
'tracks': [
    {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
    {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
    {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
],
```

Looking at your code-snippet I would guess these models are related in a One-to-one relationship. In this case `many=False` which is also the default. You could do that for both models.

I think you would be able to get to the right code with this information, if not please let me know.